# How to apply StandardScaler to a single column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn

I need to apply `StandardScaler` of `sklearn` to a single column `col1` of a DataFrame:

`df`:

```
col1  col2  col3
1     0     A
1     10    C
2     1     A
3     20    B
```

This is how I did it:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

def listOfLists(lst):
    return [[el] for el in lst]

def flatten(t):
    return [item for sublist in t for item in sublist]

scaler = StandardScaler()

df['col1'] = flatten(scaler.fit_transform(listOfLists(df['col1'].to_numpy().tolist())))
```

However, then I apply the `inverse_transform`, then it does not give me initial values of `col1`. Instead it returns the normalised values:

```
scaler.inverse_transform(flatten(scaler.fit_transform(listOfLists(df['col1'].to_numpy().tolist()))))
```

or:

```
scaler.inverse_transform(df['col1'])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could fit a scaler directly on the column (since the scaler is expecting a 2D array, you can select the column as a DataFrame by `df[['col1']]`):

```
scaler = StandardScaler()
>>> arr = scaler.fit_transform(df[['col1']]).flatten()
array([-0.90453403, -0.90453403,  0.30151134,  1.50755672])

>>> scaler.inverse_transform(arr)
array([1., 1., 2., 3.])
```

Comment: The first part works well and simplifies my approach, which is nice. But the inverse transform still gives me normalized values rather original values of `col1`.

Comment: @Fluxy maybe it's the version of scikit-learn? Because your code returns the correct initial data too.

Comment: I use the version 0.24.1

Comment: @Fluxy could you try without flattening: `scaler.inverse_transform(scaler.fit_transform(df[['col1']]))`

Comment: yes, it works well without flatten. thanks.